# Section is overlapping footer and I have tried mentioned solves

Tags: html, css

I got a section overlapping not sure why. I have tried using margins and padding to push down footer with my .div-wrap but it appears to not be working. And I have looked around and not sure what it could be. Would love some input, I bet it is an easy fix just not seeing right now. Thanks for your help.

```
    <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Mono:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap');
    </style>
    
    <section class="servies">
        <div class=" services-container">
        <h4 class=" services">
         Gone are the days of mass marketing where brands could create generic messaging and get results. Thankfully we live in a new more progressive era and brands need to be authentic and reach their auidences in a non advertisy way. I promise to help you define that message and get the word out by any means neccary. This can be in the form of idenitity and logo design, user experience and interface design, web design and development, social media marketing and campaign adertising, E-commerce design and development. What ever your creative needs are you can contact me to set up an appointment.
        </h4>
      </div>
    </section>
    
    
    <header>
          <h1>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="my-logo-01.svg" class="menu"></a>
          </h1>
        <nav>
          <a href="about.html" class="underline menu highlight">About</a>
          <a href="services.html" class="underline menu highlight">Services</a> 
          <a href="contact.html" class="underline menu highlight">Contact</a>
          <a href="blog.html" class="underline menu highlight">Blog</a>    
        </nav>  
    </header>
    
    <footer>
      <div class="footer-container">
        <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="based"> 
            <h3>
              BASED IN <br>
              CREAM CITY<br>
              <span class="highlight ">MILWAUKEE</span>
              <span class="highlight ">WISCONSIN</span>
            </h3>
          </div>
        <div class="follow-me">
          <h3>
            FOLLOW ME ON<br>
            <span class="highlight">INSTAGRAM</span>
            <span class="highlight">TWITTER</span>
            <span class="highlight">DRIBBLE</span>
            <span class="highlight">MEDIUM</span>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="inq">
          <h3>
            FOR INQUIRIES<br>
            <span class="highlight">HI@WORKBY</span><br><span class="highlight">CHRIS.ME</span>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="signup">
          <h3>
            SIGN UP FOR MY<br> NEWS LETTER
                      <form action="https://superhi1.createsend.com/t/j/s/vtikrl/" method="post"                            id="subForm" class="sign-up">
                <input placeholder="Email" id="fieldEmail" name="cm-vtikrl-vtikrl"                          type="email" required class="email-input">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
              </form>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </footer>
    `
    
        h4 {
      font-size: 48px;
      line-height: 1.2;
    }
    
    section .services {
      height: 100vh;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
     .services-container {
      padding-bottom: 112px;
         min-height: 100%;
      height: auto;
      /* Negative indent footer by its height */
      margin: 0 auto -60px;
      /* Pad bottom by footer height */
      padding: 0 0 60px;
    }
    
    footer {
      height: 100vh;
      margin-top: 112px;
      padding: 64px;
    }
    
    .footer-container {
      margin: auto;
       max-width: 900px;
    }
    
    h3 {
      font-size: 56px;
      line-height: 1.2;
       font-weight: 800;
    }
    
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
      gap: 80px 80px;
      grid-template-areas: "based follow-me" "inq signup";
     
    }
    
    .signup h3 {
      font-size: 48px;
     
    }
    
    
    
    form, .signup {
      font-size: 35px;
    }
    
    input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset] {
      background-color: #000000;
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px 32px;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: what section is overlapping what section?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `height: 100vh` which is 100% of your browsers viewport. It's also a relative height and not an absolute height. Therefore if your text inside that element is bigger than the viewport, it will overlap with the next element.

You can either hide the overlapping content, or set the height to a minimum of 100vh, so that it will automatically expand if the text is longer.

Solution #1

```
section .services {
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Solution #2

```
section .services {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```